# Not able to find commerce product in facebook app development dashboard

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am creating a project to apply CRUD operation on products using facebook eCommerce api. I
have been following this [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/commerce-platform/app-dashboard)

to  Add a Commerce Product but I don't have this option in my developer dashboard.

[image]

These are the available option but I want to add Commerce product so that I can apply crud operations on facebook store products.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/commerce-platform/project-guide: _"The Commerce API is in a closed, invite-only Beta program. Please work with your Facebook representative to get access if you have been invited to the program."_

Comment: @CBroe Is there any other way to manage products?

Comment: Product Catalog as part of Marketing API? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/catalog/overview

Comment: 2023: it's still not showing
I also tried to use a VPN to switch my location to USA but still not works
Anyone found a solution so far